# Unable to run the tensorflow in Oracle linux 6.8 due to importerror: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `glibc_2.14' not found

Tags: tensorflow

I am unable to run the tensorflow after installing in the Oracle Linux 6.8.I am getting the error : importerror: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `glibc_2.14' not found when import the tensorflow using python.

I am using GCC 4.47 version in Oracle linux 6.8.I heard that we need atleast GCC 4.7+ version to import the Tensorflow.I am not getting the correct link to install gcc 4.7+ in oracle linux 6.8.

Please help me to install tensorflow 0.10 in oracle linux 6.8.

Thanks and Regards,
Karim

Comment: Installation issues are handled at our [github](https://www.github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues) page. Note that we don't support Oracle Linux. In your case, I'd recommend installing from source.